# Istio access external sites using TLS origination behind corporate proxy

Tags: istio

I'm having troubles configuring istio to go through our corporate proxy while doing tls origination, i created a [demo](https://github.com/xDaDuck/istio-demo.git) project that reproduces this usecase and shows:

- [NO-PROXY] https requests to www.wikipedia.org **work**
- [PROXY] https requests to www.wikipedia.org **work**
- [NO-PROXY] http  requests to www.wikipedia.org **work using tls origination**
- [PROXY] http  requests to www.wikipedia.org **don't work**

To setup demo project launch istio/start.sh

[I followed this guide for proxy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/)

[and this guide for tls origination](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/)

But i haven't been able to make these 2 features work together.

Any clues on what i have been doing wrong, or if this is not possible in istio?

my current guess is that having the proxy configured with tcp protocol disables istios features required to do tls origination

I'm also starting to play with egress gateways and will update this if it works.

Meanwhile this is what you should see with the demo project:

## https no proxy - works

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -it $(microk8s.kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- sh -c "curl -I https://www.wikipedia.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1"
```

## log istio-proxy

```
[2020-01-31T12:00:39.247Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 850 4413 576 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "91.198.174.192:443" outbound|443||www.wikipedia.org 10.1.21.153:33064 91.198.174.192:443 10.1.21.153:33062 www.wikipedia.org -
```

---

## http no proxy - works

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -it $(microk8s.kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- sh -c "curl -I http://www.wikipedia.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1"
```

## log istio-proxy

```
[2020-01-31T12:02:17.012Z] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-" 0 0 181 180 "-" "curl/7.64.0" "09dddb0e-94b2-9f52-8505-e2a790f2d0c6" "www.wikipedia.org" "91.198.174.192:443" outbound|443|tls-origination|www.wikipedia.org - 91.198.174.192:80 10.1.21.153:45598 - -
```

---

## https proxy - works

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -it $(microk8s.kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- sh -c "https_proxy=$PROXY curl -I https://www.wikipedia.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1"
```

## istio log

```
[2020-01-31T12:04:38.819Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 976 4429 253 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.1.21.154:3128" outbound|3128||proxy 10.1.21.153:41184 10.1.21.154:3128 10.1.21.153:41182 - -
```

## squid-proxy log

```
1580472279.072    252 10.1.21.153 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4429 CONNECT www.wikipedia.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/91.198.174.192 -
```

---

## http proxy - wont work

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -it $(microk8s.kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- sh -c "http_proxy=$PROXY curl -I http://www.wikipedia.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1"
```

## istio log

```
[2020-01-31T12:06:40.069Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 136 681 88 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.1.21.154:3128" outbound|3128||proxy 10.1.21.153:42398 10.1.21.154:3128 10.1.21.153:42396 - -
```

## squid-proxy log

```
1580472400.158     85 10.1.21.153 TCP_MISS/301 681 HEAD http://www.wikipedia.org/ - HIER_DIRECT/91.198.174.192 -
```

I use wikipedia because it's clear what kind of request it's receiving by looking at the response code. i get 301 for http requests and 200 for https request

EDIT:

**Microk8s**

- microk8s.**kubectl version: 1.17**
- microk8s.**istioctl version: 1.3.4**

I was having the same troubles on **IBM Cloud Private**

- kubectl **version: 1.12**
- istioctl **version: 1.2.2**

Comment: Hi, what version of kubernetes and istio do You have? Also what infrastructure or platform do You use?

Comment: microk8s.kubectl version: 1.17, microk8s.istioctl version: 1.3.4.
On icp I was having the same troubles kubectl version: 1.12, istioctl version: 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command You are executing inside Your pod does not have `-L` flag that follows redirects.

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/#configuring-access-to-an-external-service):

> Notice the `-L` flag of *curl* which instructs *curl* to follow redirects. In this case, the server returned a redirect response ([301 Moved Permanently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2)) for the HTTP request to `http://edition.cnn.com/politics`. The redirect response instructs the client to send an additional request, this time using HTTPS, to `https://edition.cnn.com/politics`. For the second request, the server returned the requested content and a *200 OK* status code.

So by adding `-L` flag to curl command We can get output that follows redirections like this:

```
$ curl -I -L http://wikipedia.org
HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 12:04:56 GMT
Server: Varnish
X-Varnish: 107796482
X-Cache: cp3058 int
X-Cache-Status: int-front
Server-Timing: cache;desc="int-front"
Set-Cookie: WMF-Last-Access=03-Feb-2020;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Fri, 06 Mar 2020 12:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: WMF-Last-Access-Global=03-Feb-2020;Path=/;Domain=.wikipedia.org;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Fri, 06 Mar 2020 12:00:00 GMT
X-Client-IP: REDACTED
Location: https://wikipedia.org/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/2 301 
date: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 15:48:09 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
content-length: 234
server: mw1333.eqiad.wmnet
location: https://www.wikipedia.org/
vary: X-Forwarded-Proto
x-ats-timestamp: 1580658489
x-varnish: 325572256 37161482
age: 73007
x-cache: cp3062 miss, cp3050 hit/75960
x-cache-status: hit-front
server-timing: cache;desc="hit-front"
strict-transport-security: max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload
set-cookie: WMF-Last-Access=03-Feb-2020;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Fri, 06 Mar 2020 12:00:00 GMT
set-cookie: WMF-Last-Access-Global=03-Feb-2020;Path=/;Domain=.wikipedia.org;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Fri, 06 Mar 2020 12:00:00 GMT
x-client-ip: REDACTED
set-cookie: GeoIP=REDACTED; Path=/; secure; Domain=.wikipedia.org

HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 01:38:38 GMT
cache-control: s-maxage=86400, must-revalidate, max-age=3600
server: ATS/8.0.5
x-ats-timestamp: 1580693918
etag: W/"12be8-59c0633ed3519"
content-type: text/html
last-modified: Mon, 13 Jan 2020 14:22:18 GMT
backend-timing: D=320 t=1579084179579408
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-varnish: 335524839 907054142
age: 37578
x-cache: cp3062 miss, cp3050 hit/406421
x-cache-status: hit-front
server-timing: cache;desc="hit-front"
strict-transport-security: max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload
set-cookie: WMF-Last-Access=03-Feb-2020;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Fri, 06 Mar 2020 12:00:00 GMT
x-client-ip: REDACTED
accept-ranges: bytes
```

---

So there might be nothing wrong with Your configuration.

Try to use the following command:

```
microk8s.kubectl exec -it $(microk8s.kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- sh -c "http_proxy=$PROXY curl -I -L  http://www.wikipedia.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1"
```

Hopefully this will show You if Your cluster configuration is working with Your corporate proxy.

---

**Edit:**

Check Your squid configuration for HTTP access. According to [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_access/) documentation:

> Allowing or Denying access based on defined access lists
>
> To allow or deny a message received on an HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP port:
> http_access allow|deny [!]aclname ...
>
> NOTE on default values:
>
> If there are no "access" lines present, the default is to deny the
> request.
>
> If none of the "access" lines cause a match, the default is the
> opposite of the last line in the list.  If the last line was deny, the
> default is allow.  Conversely, if the last line is allow, the default
> will be deny.  For these reasons, it is a good idea to have an "deny
> all" entry at the end of your access lists to avoid potential
> confusion.
>
> This clause supports both fast and slow acl types. See
> http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl for details.

In [`proxy.yaml`](https://github.com/xDaDuck/istio-demo/blob/master/istio/proxy.yaml#L18) You have the following:

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

It denies CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports.

I suggest modifying the squid configuration snippet to match ports/protocols You are using. As this could be the reason why `HTTP` requests with proxy are not working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but curl here is just an example, we are trying to follow the guide where redirection is not needed (i.e. the second part of the guide: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/#tls-origination-for-egress-traffic). we need tls-origination to be made by istio, if we follow redirect the https request is done by our client, which is not what we need.

Comment: If we allow http connections on the proxy which is external to the mesh, then istio would not be able to do tls-origination, so even that solution doesn't work for us.